# Sending command to server through SOAP service and setting connection in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, soap-client

I have a set of functions that are taken from server's web service (written in SOAP protocol). I want to connect to this server and send commands according to these specific functions via a console app.

However, I suppose I need to establish a connection to the server by using classes like "Endpoint", "HttpBinding", "Bindingprovider" etc. (I do not know I am right or wrong about these classes) However, due to all my attempts I could not connect to this remote server for sending commands.

I have its service address, service url, QName info, login credentials (username, password). I used these parameters in a number of combinations, but I am really stucked with connecting. What are the protocols for connecting, sample codes, or anything that may help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have specifically listed out C#, I am assuming that you have a little working knowledge of Microsoft Visual Studio.

1. In Visual Studio, create a new `Console Application`
2. Right click on your project and click on `Add Service Reference`
3. Copy paste the SOAP URL which you have and click on discover. At this point, you should be able to see what all `services` and `methods (operations)` the service allows you to execute; Give it any convenient `Name Space`
4. Import the necessary namespace by making use of `using`
5. Create a service object: Example: tempConversionService is my Name Space and TempConvertSoapClient is my service client and serviceObj is my service object which can be used to invoke methods in the client (make use of `.` after the object so that you can see the different methods associated with the service
6. Sit back and have fun invoking web services!

Example:

```
tempConversionService.TempConvertSoapClient serviceObj = new tempConversionService.TempConvertSoapClient();
    Console.WriteLine(serviceObj.CelsiusToFahrenheit(100));
```

You can make it your application specific. Pass the login credentials, authenticate yourself, then do whatever you want to do with your web service.

Hope this helps!